# Symfony Error in Optional Form Field

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have the next form in Symfony 2.7:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($entity)
            ->add('laboratorio',null, array('required'=>false)->getForm();
```

"laboratorio" is a field of type entity. But when I submit the form whitout select a value I got the next error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 
'SELECT n0_.id AS id0, n0_.codigo AS codigo1,
n0_.nombre AS nombre2 FROM nom_laboratorio 
n0_ WHERE n0_.id IN (?)' with params [""]:
```

I think that Symfony should not try to find the entity by his id when the optional field is blank.

Even I try whith $this->submit($request,true) instead of $this->handleRequest($request) in the controller but nothing change.

There is something I am ignoring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use the [empty_data](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/entity.html#empty-data) option.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($entity)
    ->add('laboratorio',null, array(
        'required'    => false,
        'placeholder' => 'Choose the laboratorio',
        'empty_data'  => null,
    )->getForm();
```

Comment: empty_data only work whith a valid integer value. I tray whith a new empty instance of the class but nothing.

Comment: What exactly happens when you choose "Choose the laboratorio" option?

Comment: With 'empty_data'  => null the database error is trowed.

Comment: I've tried empty_data + placeholder in Symfony 2.7 and it did the trick. In Symfony < 2.6 you should use empty_value instead of placeholder. Please make sure that null is passed to a post parameter if you choose placeholder/empty_value option.